# Merge two lists of tuples into one

Tags: python

Supposing we have two lists, where `list1` contains initial values, and list 2 has all the values to update in the first list:

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]
list2 = [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]
```

The desired result is a merged list3, of list2 values inserted into list1 values, using to the first element as index:

```
list3 = [('a', 5), ('b', 0), ('c', 3)]
```

I tried running the following code without success:

```
list3 = list1 + list2 
list3 = list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: The logic is if both lists has the same first value than take the one with the highest second value? do you add the second values? please explain

Comment: As @omri_saadon alluded, what exactly are the rules to combine them?  Does list2 always supercede list1? Or does non-zero trump zero? Or the higher value wins? Or what?

Comment: You'll need to explain why the desired result contains `('b', 0), ('c', 3)` because it is not clear. You're neither overriding the tuple with the 'higher' value, or the 'second' value, or something intuitive...

Comment: Perhaps the values are to be added, but it's not clear from the example since one of the values is zero.

Comment: List1 contains all the default values

Comment: @colbalt011 That isn't really telling us anything. Does `list2` simply overwrite `list1` duplicates?

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you want the values from `list2`, along with everything in `list1` that's not in `list2`.  Do you care about the order?

Answer (score 4):

By using dict, you could achieve it like this :

```
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]
list2 = [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]
d1 = dict(list1)
d1.update(dict(list2))
list(d1.items())
>>> [('a', 5), ('b', 0), ('c', 3)]
```

Comment: This is assuming `list2` is overriding `list1`, i'm not sure this is the OP intention.

Comment: this solution solves the problem stated in the question, but you're right, the OP was not clear, and finally, the solution of @Ajax1234 is the good one.

Comment: Personally, I prefer this solution for as more simple and readable. It also seems to [run a bit faster for me](https://github.com/asfaltboy/so-python-benchmarks/blob/master/47183095-merge-two-lists-of-tuples-into-one.ipynb) (on python 3.6).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
list1 = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]
list2 = [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in list1+list2:
   d[a].append(b)

final_data = sorted([(a, max(b)) for a, b in d.items()], key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 5), ('b', 0), ('c', 3)]
```